# OpenVPN DD WRT route tun1 to allow access from other PC's

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, dd-wrt

i do have a little problem.

I set up an OpenVPN connection (client) (which runs using DD WRT on a router) to an OpenVPN server which works great, the thing is i dont know how to route the traffic through the tunnel.

I am able to ping the VPN Server on the router but i cannot access nor ping the vpn server using a pc which is connected to the router.

The OpenVPN client created a tun1 but i do not know how to forward / route everything pointing to 192.168.50.1 through the tunnel on a pc.

Hope someone can help.

Regards

Comment: Is the OpenVPN Server a 3rd party or one that you're running?

Comment: i am running the server currently -  its not 3rd party and it runs locally using 192.168.60.x while the server has 192.168.50.x

Comment: I'll create an answer with the config options required.  What OS is the server running on (Linux, OpenWrt, DD-WRT, etc.)?

Comment: the openvpn server runs on linux - the connection between client and server is site 2 site, the connection between them works (the routers can ping each other) but clients (pcs) connected to the client router cant ping the server

Comment: If my answer below does not work, please post your server and client config, anonymizing sensitive info before doing so _(i.e. generalize the WAN IP/DDNS and port #)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to:

- Route traffic behind a router (i.e. remote access), you'll use the `route` directive in the server config:

  ```ini
  # Linux:

    # Pushed Routes #
    #---------------------------------------------------
      push                'route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0'

      push                'dhcp-option    DNS 192.168.1.1'
      push                'dhcp-option    WINS 192.168.1.1'

      client-to-client    '1'


  # OpenWrt:

    # Pushed Routes #
    #---------------------------------------------------
      list    push                'route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0'

      list    push                'dhcp-option    DNS 192.168.1.1'
      list    push                'dhcp-option    WINS 192.168.1.1'

      option  client_to_client    '1'
  ```

  - Where `192.168.1.0/24` is the subnet behind the VPN you want to access
- Route all traffic, including web traffic, through the VPN, use the [`redirect-gateway`](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#routing-all-client-traffic-including-web-traffic-through-the-vpn) directive

  - *This directive will vary depending on the OS the OpenVPN server is running on:*

    ```ini
    push                'redirect-gateway def1'
    ```

General FYI:

Many simply use the generic configs found online, however, the most benefit and best security comes from tuning the configs.

- *I have a tuned server config and client config on [my GitHub](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN) as an example.*

  - *`tls_auth` needs to be updated to `tls_crypt` in the Server config (see man page below)*.

I always recommend taking the time to read the OpenVPN [HowTo](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/) (~15min) & [man page](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-0/) (~45min).